# Recreating Tab Pages with just Buttons and Grids - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

This is my first time to program in C# as well as create a program in WPF. I have been searching through the internet for the past two hours to see if there was a way to recreate this kind of design( https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA5RZ.jpg ). I first thought of creating a tabbed page with the tabs customized, but it seemed like I could not accomplish it. Another way to do it was to make each of the header into button and the grid changes. So far I am getting nowhere. So I would like to know if there's a better way to do it?

TL;DR:

How to accomplish this design ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA5RZ.jpg ) the best way possible? With the buttons changing the content of the lower panel and all.

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible to reuse **ContentControl**?

Comment: @Sometowngeek Not exactly Content Control... For example, if I click Home button, there are three panels, when I click Settings button there is no panels and just a few buttons and radio buttons. I am asking a way for me to recreate how a tabControl works, but with just buttons and Grid(or something else if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I'm pretty close to the main window (without content).

[image]

Code to reproduce (put inside the main window root):

```
<Window.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
         <Setter Property="Template">
             <Setter.Value>
                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                     <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                         <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                     </Border>
                 </ControlTemplate>
             </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
     </Style>
 </Window.Resources>

 <Grid> 
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="98"/>
         <RowDefinition/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <Grid Grid.Row="1">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="280"/>
             <ColumnDefinition/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
         <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="3,10,10,10" >
             <Grid.Effect>
                 <DropShadowEffect Color="LightGray" ShadowDepth="3" Opacity=".5" />
             </Grid.Effect>
             <Border CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" Background="#FFF5F6F5" />
             <ContentControl x:Name="ContentCenter">

             </ContentControl>
         </Grid>

         <Grid Margin="10,10,3,10">
             <Grid.Effect>
                 <DropShadowEffect Color="LightGray" ShadowDepth="3" Opacity=".5" />
             </Grid.Effect>
             <Border CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" Background="#FFF5F6F5" />

             <Border  Height="30" Margin="12,15,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" CornerRadius="15" BorderBrush="#FFEBEBEB" BorderThickness="1">
                 <Grid>
                     <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="25" Source="Images/magnifier.PNG" Margin="10,2,0,2" />
                     <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockSearch" Text="Search" Margin="39,6,163,4" Foreground="#FF5B5B5B" />
                     <TextBox Text="" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="35,0,10,0" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="#FF5B5B5B" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
                 </Grid>
             </Border>
             <ContentControl x:Name="ContentSide" Margin="0,45,0,0">

             </ContentControl>
         </Grid>
     </Grid>

     <Grid>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition />
             <ColumnDefinition />
             <ColumnDefinition />
             <ColumnDefinition />
             <ColumnDefinition />
             <ColumnDefinition />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <Button Margin="10" x:Name="ButtonHome">
             <Image Source="Images/home.PNG" />
         </Button>

         <Button Margin="10" x:Name="ButtonAudit" Grid.Column="1">
             <Image Source="Images/audit.PNG" />
         </Button>

         <Button Margin="10" x:Name="ButtonReports" Grid.Column="2">
             <Image Source="Images/reports.PNG" />
         </Button>

         <Button Margin="10" x:Name="ButtonAccount" Grid.Column="3">
             <Image Source="Images/account.PNG" />
         </Button>

         <Button Margin="10" x:Name="ButtonHelp" Grid.Column="4">
             <Image Source="Images/help.png" />
         </Button>

         <Button Margin="10" x:Name="ButtonSettings" Grid.Column="5">
             <Image Source="Images/settings.PNG" />
         </Button>
     </Grid> 
 </Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as TextBox).Text.Length == 0)
            TextBlockSearch.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        else
            TextBlockSearch.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

This layout has two ContentControls, one into the "sidebar" and one into the "center". Use then to hold the dynamic content.

Button Images (create an Images folder in the root for the project and add those files):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If the entire lower portion without the buttons were to be changing, would I be using contentControl on the whole grid? (Ex. Both the one with search panel and the empty panel would be changed to say, 3 panels with one additional panel containing the date.)

Comment: Yes. In that case, put one big ContentControl on the lower portion, then you can create a UserControl with the lateral search bar and the empty panel, both with their own ContentControls. With WPF, you can nest things as much as you want ; )

Comment: That's great! Thank you! ContentControl is the UI element that I was looking for!